# How to convert unicode characters into corresponding emojis?

Tags: javascript, json, regex, unicode

I'm doing something similar to this [website](https://dev.to/raicuparta/ditching-worthless-friends-with-facebook-data-and-javascript-3f2i) with my data. I have the Unicode in the format below, and the code to convert UTF16 into UTF string works.

```
function decodeFBEmoji (fbString) {
  // Convert String to Array of hex codes
  const codeArray = (
    fbString  // starts as '\u00f0\u009f\u0098\u00a2'
    .split('')
    .map(char => (
      char.charCodeAt(0)  // convert '\u00f0' to 0xf0
    )
  );  // result is [0xf0, 0x9f, 0x98, 0xa2]

  // Convert plain JavaScript array to Uint8Array
  const byteArray = Uint8Array.from(codeArray);

  // Decode byte array as a UTF-8 string
  return new TextDecoder('utf-8').decode(byteArray);  // ''
```

I am trying to extract the Unicode from the text string, and then replace it with its decoded Unicode to display as a proper emoji. I tried to use regex to extract the Unicode string, however, it converts to the random garbage character, and regex results out null.
How can I replace the given code with its emoji without changing the rest of the text?

```
function replaceEmoji(text){
      let str = "lorem ipsum lorem ipsum \u00e2\u009d\u00a4\u00ef\u00b8\u008f lorem ipsum"; 
      let res = str.match(/[\\]\w+/g); 
      console.log(str);
      console.log(res); //Result is null
}
```

[Console output of the above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbhFC.png)

Edit: [Regex Pattern I tested](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17NYv.png)

Comment: I don't know much about regex, so I used regexer and the pattern matched the test string, hence I used it. The unicode only has a single '\' in every string in the json file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to decode some UTF8 but you're mixing up JS string escapes and bytes.

When you type `\uXXXX` you type an escape for a unicode codepoint (just like `\n` is an escape for a newline), so this is true for instance: `"\u0041" == "A"`

This is the reason your regex cannot match anything, there is actually no backslash `\` in the string. Now it's not clear in what form you have your UTF8 coming in, but if it is like you wrote it it is a series of UTF8 bytes which need to be decoded like so:

```js
const utf8 = new Uint8Array(
    Array.prototype.map.call(
        "lorem ipsum lorem ipsum \u00e2\u009d\u00a4\u00ef\u00b8\u008f lorem ipsum", 
        c => c.charCodeAt(0)
    )
);
console.log(new TextDecoder('utf8').decode(utf8));
```

Comment: I ran this code and it works on its own for a particular string. But, I am mapping over an array for strings, and this does not work.

EDIT: this works. I had to use the String function on my variable.