Incorrect decoding of a JSON file with Unicode characters using readFileSync and JSON.parse
I need to interpret a .json file saved in UTF-8 using nodejs/typescript. The file contains text with Unicode characters like this:
[
   {
     "media": [
       {
         "title": "La codifica \u00c3\u00a8 corretta!\u00f0\u009f\u0098\u0085"
       }
     ]
   }
]

If I write the following code
const fInstaPosts = FS.readFileSync("file.json");

const instaPosts = JSON.parse(fInstaPosts.toString());

console.log(instaPosts[0].media[0].title);

what I get is this
'La codifica Ã¨ corretta!ð\x9F\x98\x85'
while its correct decoding is this
'La codifica è corretta!'
what am I doing wrong?

If you know the encoding, use the encoding: From the docs: readFileSync("file.json", { encoding: 'utf8' }. I don't know if that's the only problem here though...

Yes thanks but I had already tried, but nothing changes

Th problem seems to be the JSON.parse(), that transform the unicode sequence "\u00c3\u00a8" to the incorrect chars.

It looks like your original data isn't in utf-8; I'd try reading it in with the other supported encodings to start with, and see if one of them matches.

è in UTF-8, encoded as JSON, would be \u00e8. Whatever you got there, is not UTF-8. "a .json file saved in UTF-8" - just because the file was saved using UTF-8 character encoding, doesn't necessarily mean that what the JSON contains, is UTF-8 as well.

Your data appears to have been UTF-8 encoded twice.

@CBroe no in UTF-8 is 0xC3 0xA8 that is the same in my file https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+00E8

I found the solution in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/73087595/2932629
